# error starting npm: node_modules not present in root directory of web app

Tags: node.js, express, npm

so I'm just starting to learn how to create a node.js web app and I have both node and npm installed already but for some reason I can't run `npm start` in my website directory after running `npm init`.

Checked other questions related to this and none of the answers worked for me so far.

kindly see the error message below.

```
> portfolio@1.0.0 start /Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- /Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio/server.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio/server.js' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macintosh/.npm/_logs/2020-07-31T09_30_20_392Z-debug.log
```

this is the log file below.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~prestart: portfolio@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~start: portfolio@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio
10 silly lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node server.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle portfolio@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: portfolio@1.0.0 start: node server.js
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid portfolio@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error portfolio@1.0.0 start: node server.js
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the portfolio@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

Clearly says that you have imported **express** *npm package* in your *server.js* but it has not installed in your project folder. When you will install **express** or any package in your project you will see it as dependencies in *package.json* and gets installed in node_modules/packagefolder. So please make sure that you have installed **express** package.

Answer (score 0):

```
***> portfolio@1.0.0 start /Users/macintosh/Documents/Portfolio
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^***
```

This error happens, because the ".js" file that runs the program is outside the project's rais folder.
Analyze more carefully and move the file ".js" to the correct folder and everything will be solved!